# Reload page after file download

Tags: php, jquery, fpdf

I'm using fpdf to generate and print a pdf file after the server(php) performs some processing. The pdf file is downloaded this way

```
    $this->pdf->Output('D', 'pins.pdf');
```

However, what I need is to reload the form after the file has been downloaded. Hence, my question is that, is there a way to reload a page using jquery after a download prompt displays on the browser?
If not, any ideas on how to do this will be much appreciated because it is important both to print the pdf file that is being generated by fpdf and to reload the form.
Than

Comment: This can only be done using client side logic, so javascript.

Comment: `window.location.href`?

Comment: Reload after the file is downloaded? What about when the user uses a download manager (if they still exist assuming you're supporting them?) and finishes the download 3 days later? Would they magically get redirected to a page?